# Query gives a blank page

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select name, phone from approval(tableB) using condition in users(tableA), I got the below code

```
$email = 'email';

$sql = "SELECT phone, name FROM approval RIGHT JOIN users ON users.email=email.$assigned";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result) { // output data of each row 
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
     echo "<center><table class='table table-bordered'><thead><tbody><tr><td>Name</td><td>" . $row["name"]. " </td></tr><tr><td>Phone</td><td> " . $row["phone"]. " </td></tr><tr><td></td><td> ".file_get_contents("jquery.php")."</td></tr></thead></tbody‌​> </center>"; 
       } 
       echo "</table>"; 
   } else { 
    echo "<center>!Sorry you have not been paired.</center>"; 
   } 
} 
$conn->close(); 
?>
```

on running it, it gives me a blank page.

Comment: what are you expecting? you haven't echo out anything. Add var_dump($result) and see what shows up

Comment: if ($result) {
 
  // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<center><table class='table table-bordered'><thead><tbody><tr><td>Name</td><td>" . $row["name"]. " </td></tr><tr><td>Phone</td><td> " . $row["phone"]. " </td></tr><tr><td></td><td> ".file_get_contents("jquery.php")."</td></tr></thead></tbody> </center>";
     
  }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
      echo "<center>!Sorry you have not been paired.</center>";
  
}
}
$conn->close();
?>

Comment: that is what i echoed

Comment: enable error_reporting and show what error it shows

Comment: look like your sql query is wrong,
You have to check that

Comment: Made the title more generic for search. Please edit and include the error from the mysql log in your question.

Comment: What is the value of your variable `$assigned`? Did you define it?